# How to combine similarly structured directories?

Tags: bash, filesystem

I have two directories that look like this:

```
/folder1/sub1/file1.txt
/folder1/sub1/file2.txt
/folder1/sub2/file1.txt
/folder1/sub2/file2.txt

/folder2/sub1/file3.txt
/folder2/sub1/file4.txt
/folder2/sub2/file3.txt
/folder2/sub2/file4.txt
```

I'd like to copy all of the files from `folder2` into `folder1` without deleting any of the existing folders, so that I end up with the following:

```
/folder1/sub1/file1.txt
/folder1/sub1/file2.txt
/folder1/sub1/file3.txt
/folder1/sub1/file4.txt
/folder1/sub2/file1.txt
/folder1/sub2/file2.txt
/folder1/sub2/file3.txt
/folder1/sub2/file4.txt
```

how can I accomplish this via the terminal?

Answer (score 9):

`rsync` is a perfect tool for this job:

```
rsync -av folder2/ folder1
```

The `-v` option is optional, but it lists files as they're processed. The slash after `folder2` is **required**, otherwise you'll get `folder1/folder2/file1.txt` instead of `folder1/file1.txt`.

If you're not sure whether the command does what you want, add the `--dry-run` option to show what would actually happen.